# Javascript asynchronous filling bars using callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am new to javascript and unfortunately (or fortunately?) have tackle with the issue of asynchronous events in js. I know we should use callbacks and I did try using them with no good results.

There are 3 functions that each fills a bar, how could I use callbacks to make the bars fill one after the other?

```
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;
var lifeRemaining = 100 - (getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy) + getPercentage(
    effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy));

function ShowBar1() {
    if (x1 < getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x1 += 1;
        var y1 = "width: " + x1.toString() + "%";
        progressBar1.setAttribute("style", y1);
        progressBar1.textContent = x1.toString() + "%";
    }
}

function ShowBar2() {
    if (x2 < getPercentage(effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x2 += 1;
        var y2 = "width: " + x2.toString() + "%";
        progressBar2.setAttribute("style", y2);
        progressBar2.textContent = x2.toString() + "%"
    }
}

function ShowBar3() {
    if (x3 < lifeRemaining) {
        x3 += 1;
        var y3 = "width: " + x3.toString() + "%";
        progressBar3.setAttribute("style", y3);
        progressBar3.textContent = x3.toString() + "%";
    }
}
setInterval(ShowBar1, 50);
setInterval(ShowBar2, 50);
setInterval(ShowBar3, 50);
```

Comment: how do you stop your Intervals, seems it continue to works forever, just do nothing because of condition?

Comment: the "getPercentage" function returns a set number based on values of age and lifeExpectancy (all defined in the preceding code, I have only copied a section of the code here). the ShowBar functions are only supposed to work as long as the 'if' conditions within them are met. The code seems to be working fine, what I see on screen is three bars filling   simultaneously.

Comment: No. showBar will works forever, because you didn't stop it, just because your if condition will not be matched showBar will do nothing, but anyway will be called every 50 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, finally solved it, using call backs, all three bars start filling one after the other, see

```
  function ShowBar1(callback) {
      var x1 = 0;
      var y1;
      progressBar2.setAttribute("style", "width: 0%");
      progressBar3.setAttribute("style", "width: 0%");
      var test = setInterval(function() {
          x1 += 1;
          y1 = "width: " + x1.toString() + "%";
          progressBar1.setAttribute("style", y1);
          progressBar1.textContent = x1.toString() + "%";
          if (x1 === getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy)) {
              clearInterval(test);
              callback(); //bar 2 starts filling using callback
          }
      }, 50);
  }

  function ShowBar2() {
      var x2 = 0;
      var y2;
      var test2 = setInterval(function() {
          x2 += 1;
          y2 = "width: " + x2.toString() + "%";
          progressBar2.setAttribute("style", y2);
          progressBar2.textContent = x2.toString() + "%"
          if (x2 === getPercentage(effLifeRemaining,
              lifeExpectancy)) {
              clearInterval(test2);  //bar 3 starts filling from this point
              var x3 = 0;
              var y3;
              var test3 = setInterval(function() {
                  x3 += 1;
                  y3 = "width: " + x3.toString() + "%";
                  progressBar3.setAttribute("style", y3);
                  progressBar3.textContent = x3.toString() +
                      "%";
                  if (x3 == lifeRemaining) {
                      clearInterval(test3);
                  }
              }, 50);
          }
      }, 50);
  }
  ShowBar1(ShowBar2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use interval if you have callback. You can refer below for sample callback:

```
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;
var lifeRemaining = 100 - (getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy) + getPercentage(
    effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy));

function ShowBar1(callback) {
    if (x1 < getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x1 += 1;
        var y1 = "width: " + x1.toString() + "%";
        progressBar1.setAttribute("style", y1);
        progressBar1.textContent = x1.toString() + "%";
    }

    return callback;
}

function ShowBar2(callback) {
    if (x2 < getPercentage(effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x2 += 1;
        var y2 = "width: " + x2.toString() + "%";
        progressBar2.setAttribute("style", y2);
        progressBar2.textContent = x2.toString() + "%"
    }

    return callback;
}

function ShowBar3() {
    if (x3 < lifeRemaining) {
        x3 += 1;
        var y3 = "width: " + x3.toString() + "%";
        progressBar3.setAttribute("style", y3);
        progressBar3.textContent = x3.toString() + "%";
    }
}

var bar2 = ShowBar1(ShowBar2);
var bar3 = bar2(ShowBar3);
bar3();
```

You can refer below for callback that executes the 3 function with a 50 ms delay. I just remove extra code for simplification.

```
function ShowBar1(callback, callback2) {
    console.log('ShowBar1');
    callback(callback2);
}

function ShowBar2(callback) {
    console.log('ShowBar2');
    callback();
}

function ShowBar3() {
    console.log('ShowBar3');

    setTimeout(ShowBar1, 50, ShowBar2, ShowBar3);
}

ShowBar1(ShowBar2, ShowBar3);
```

Answer (score 0):

All your three Intervals running together forever in parallel

You have to do something like this:

```
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;
var lifeRemaining = 100 - (getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy) + getPercentage(
    effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy));

var curInterval;

curInterval = setInterval(ShowBar1, 50)

function ShowBar1() {
    if (x1 < getPercentage(age, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x1 += 1;
        var y1 = "width: " + x1 + "%";
        progressBar1.setAttribute("style", y1);
        progressBar1.textContent = x1 + "%";
    } else {
        clearInterval(curInterval);
        curInterval = setInterval(ShowBar2, 50)
    }
}

function ShowBar2() {
    if (x2 < getPercentage(effLifeRemaining, lifeExpectancy)) {
        x2 += 1;
        var y2 = "width: " + x2 + "%";
        progressBar2.setAttribute("style", y2);
        progressBar2.textContent = x2 + "%"
    } else {
        clearInterval(curInterval);
        curInterval = setInterval(ShowBar3, 50)
    }
}

function ShowBar3() {
    if (x3 < lifeRemaining) {
        x3 += 1;
        var y3 = "width: " + x3 + "%";
        progressBar3.setAttribute("style", y3);
        progressBar3.textContent = x3 + "%";
    } else {
        clearInterval(curInterval);
    }
}
```